# how to start the neovim gio from the cli

Tags: linux, neovim

I'm trying to switch from vim/gvim to neovim on Linux. Up to now my standard workflow started with opening the cli, navigate to my project directory, and run `gvim <filename>` with the file I intend to start working with.

With neovim I can start it from the KDE menu to get a nice GUI. according to the menu settings, it simply runs `nvim` with an optional filename parameter. But I don't find the way to run nvim from the cli in a way, that it starts the GUI. Running `nvim <filename>` simply starts the cli UI.

Google gave me a lot of interesting information, but not, what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are different GUIs for neovim. Check which one do you actually use and start it from the command line. Navigate to the KDE menu for neovim GUI, right-click on it and select Edit application... Go to the Application tab and check the Command edit box. There you'll see the actual command which is run by KDE when you select the corresponding menu item. You can create your own shell script or alias which will run this command and use it on the command line.

**UPDATE**

Maybe some parameter or environment variable is passed to nvim so it changes its behavior. You can try to see what system call KDE actually performs to start the editor. For example, I'm using KDE plasma, so `pidof plasmashell` gives me the pid which I need. Then:

```
strace -f -v -e trace=execve -p `pidof plasmashell` &> plasma.trace
```

After that go to KDE menu and start neovim. Terminate the strace command with Ctrl-C and check the plasma.trace file for the execve system calls made to start the neovim process.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The menu entry says, it runs nvim. I also have nvim-gtk and nvim-qt installed, but none of them are the one, that it starts. Actually both of them are suboptimal in different ways.

Comment: Maybe you can try to check some hidden parameters by checking the actual system calls made to start the nvim, as I explain in the update to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much again. Turns out, the menu entry starts konsole with nvim inside. In the meantime I've tried with nvim-qt, but I didn't even manage to persuade it to show the menu as a Qt menu. The nvim-gtk seems to put more emphasis on nice look, than on usability and integration with freedesktop standards. Therefore for me there are two ways forward: if there's a good tutorial how to write a nvim UI, I could write my own. If not, I better stick with vim and wait, till a usefull UI is available.